# Bootstrap (v4.4.1) collapse not working with jQuery (v3.5.0) - Error: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is a simple example below copied from [getBootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#navbarTogglerDemo01). I'm using the latest versions of Bootstrap (v4.4.1) and jQuery (v3.5.0).

But still, Bootstrap collapse is not working. When I checked DevTools Console, I got this `Error: Cannot convert object to primitive value`.

Any idea why is this happening? Is it some update issue or bug?

(Note: *I would have created snippet but it doesn't have jquery v3.5.0*)

[**Update**: I checked and jquery v3.4.1. is working fine]

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's indeed a bug related to jQuery 3.5
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4665